# Passing a string, around quotation marks into another string, all in a mutli line string

Tags: c#, strings

the title might sound confusing but i have a multi line string which is my source code to be compiled. Inside that string i have a messagebox that will display another string, inside that string i want to pass a string. It got very confusing with all the quotation marks but i finally got it working:

```
        string source = @"
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        using System.Windows.Forms;

        namespace Compiler
            {
                static class Program
                {
                    static void Main()
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(""this is my message: "" + """ + txtMessage.Text + @"""" + @");
                    }
                }
            }";
```

This returns: MessageBox.Show("this is my message: " + "Hello"); providing the value in txtMessage = Hello

So this works but is very messy, also if i pass something like "hi, into txtMessage that will mess it up because of the quotation mark, kinda like a sql injection. Would there be a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you have a look at the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480724/escape-double-quotes-in-string

Answer (score 3):

No matter how you do it, it'll be always messy. Instead of hardcoding the strings use resource files instead. You can embed `*.txt` files inside the exe/dll and easily read them without having to escape anything.

See this question on Stack Overflow: [How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)
. You'll find everything you need there.

To insert the message use the `{0}` placeholder with

```
string.Format(stringFromResource, txtMessage.Text);
```

Comment: +1 This is a good approach. a) Things indeed are not messy this way. b) There is clear separation of concerns -- real code is apart from data.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options really:

1. Add arguments to `Main` so the string can be passed when you run the compiled program; i.e. don't put the string into the source
2. Perform your own escaping on the string you're putting into the source code

E.g. for number 2 at the least you'll have to escape `"` to `\"` and escape any `\` which is not part of an escape sequence (or just always escape it).

```
string SanitizeString(string input)
{
    if (input == null)
    {
        // throw or return string.Empty
    }

    // Your logic to make the string safe here
}
```

I'd be worried about getting number 2 right so I'd be more likely to go for option 1.